# sigabrt received when using CorePlot

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-plot, sigabrt

I'm using XCode 4.2 to develop a simple app using CorePlot 1.0. I've receiving "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

This issue has come up on many other threads, but the other threads seem to agree that the problem is setting the "Other Linker Flags". The setup instructions say to add "-ObjC" linker flag, but some others include "-all_load" and "-Obj-C". I've tried them all.

Some threads say to make sure the header search path is set up correctly. Mine is set up as an absolute path: "/Developer/projects/CorePlotDemo/CorePlotHeaders".

I get this error when running this [example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13269/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-1) as well as my "real" application.

I don't know what else to try, any suggestions?

Comment: Which selector and which class is it complaining about?

Comment: I'm getting:


`2012-07-26 08:07:31.862 CorePlotDemo[650:207] -[CPTMutableNumericData setDataType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b07c00

2012-07-26 08:07:31.863 CorePlotDemo[650:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CPTMutableNumericData setDataType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b07c00'
`

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a category method that's not being loaded correctly. The "-all_load" linker flag should fix that.

Comment: Thank you both for your help. I don't know what I did wrong but I eventually just reverted back to a working version of my app (before I integrated CorePlot) and just integrated it again. This time I must have done it correctly because it now works. Not sure what I did wrong.